# LinkButton click event not firing in iOS and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, buttonclick, asplinkbutton

ASP Code :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnShow" runat="server">Show Addition</asp:LinkButton>
```

Code Behind :

```
Protected Sub lbtnShow(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbtnShow.Click
   //Code Here
End Sub
```

Similarly, click for "Anchor tag" and "Hyperlink" is not working in iOS and iPad.

Comment: @NimitParekh I think the OP is developing a web app, and isn't interested in native development links at this time.

Comment: @NimitParekh : I am developing a web app which is running successfully in IE9,IE10,IE11,Google Chrome and Mozilla . But , while i am testing the app in mac OS(Browser : Safari) , the click for "Anchor tag" , Link Button and "Hyperlink" is not working at all. Right now ,I don't want to learn iOS concepts . Please let me know , is there any solution for the above mentioned Issue !!

Comment: @Hemang : I am developing a web app which is running successfully in IE9,IE10,IE11,Google Chrome and Mozilla . But , while i am testing the app in mac OS(Browser : Safari) , the click for "Anchor tag" , Link Button and "Hyperlink" is not working at all. Please let me know , is there any solution for the above mentioned Issue !!

Comment: @PranavKumar, Sorry. I've no idea about `asp.net` !